# Putting fuel in my vehicle. Having trouble starting

Tags: starting, fuel-system, hyundai, santa-fe

When I fill up my 2008 Santa Fe, I have trouble keeping it started. I have to start it 3 or 4 times then start it in neutral, throw it in drive and take off really fast. It will eventually started. No problems until I fill up again and the cycle starts again. Please help!

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: what do you mean by keeping it started?Do you overfill it?

Comment: No I never overfill. It will start and before I put it in drive it kills. It will do this a few times.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds a lot like what happened to my Corolla. It turned out to be a evaporative system issue. It ranges from a defective fuel cap to issues where system pressure is leaking and it is a real pain to diagnose. When you fill up your gas tank stop at the first click-no more. Do not overfill.

Comment: @karen Check the purge valve, this is a known issue on Hyundai’s.

Comment: @Ben  I believe there are 2 of them, 1 near the gas tank and 1 near the intake manifold. In the case of my  Corolla it was the one near the intake and the hard starting was due the vapor flooding it and it would only start after it cleared,

Comment: the one on the intake is generally called a purge valve/solenoid. the one off the canister is a vent solenoid or canister close valve.